# How to set selected value on dropdown menu from database

Tags: php, database

I have a table with three columns. The first two contain some auto generated data from a database and the column contains drop down menus with 3 different categories:

```
<tr id='+response[i]['itemcode']+'> 
  <th>'+response[i]['itemcode']+'</th>
  <th>'+response[i]['temaxia']+'</th>
  <th>
    <select class="status">
      <option value="incomplete">incomplete</option>
      <option value="unfinished">ημιτελής</option>
      <option value="complete">complete</option>
    </select>
  </th>
</tr>
```

I use a PHP script to udpate my database based on the selection in the dropdown menu. 
What I want to do now is to show in the dropdown menu the values that exist in the database. I know that there is an attribute called: "selected" and you can use it as following:

```
<select>
  <option value="complete">complete</option>
  <option value="incomplete">incomplete</option>
  <option value="unfinished" selected>unfinished</option>
```

But this is not what I am looking for. What I need is ideally an attribute which I can set on the parent element:

```
<select>
```

and populate it with my value from the database.
Is there something line this?

I attach a screenshot of the interface.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also add "value" attribute in select.

Like : `<select value="your-value-here">`

Comment: Although I add the value as you say and I can see it on my html code (using Firebug) it doesn't appear as the selection in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Add `name` attribute to select, then the value will be in

```
$_POST['select_name'] // or $_GET['select_name'], depends on form method attribute
```

Select will be

```
<select name="select_name">
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done what you say but the value on the dropdown menu doesn't change based on the value of "name" attribute.